# Floating Point Precision Error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, floating-accuracy, lispworks

I am having problem with the LISP expression below. There is floating precision error while doing sum for floating point numbers.

```
CL-USER> (+ -380 -158.27 -35.52)

Actual:   -573.79004
Expected: -573.79000
```

Please suggest me how can I achieve the expected result in LISP (I am using Lispworks).

Comment: why would you expect anything else if you compute with floats of a certain precision?

Comment: Actually, I am porting an application from ORACLE to lisp and the ORACLE application gives -573.79000 but the LISP returns -573.79004. This has caused many mismatches while testing the end result of the applications.

Comment: @bigyanshr Sounds like your tests need a wider threshold. In particular, you want any values within, say, 0.00005 to be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Floats are not exact

Floats represent a subset of mathematical reals with certain *precision*, they are **not** *exact* numbers. Round off errors are *inevitable*.

The ANSI Common Lisp standard provides for [4(!) levels of float precision: short, single, double, long](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_short_.htm) (all implementations provide at least 2). Neither is exact, but ORACLE is probably using `double`, so if you stick with doubles, you should be fine.

## Theory

Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf).

## Use integers and ratios if you want exact numbers

If you want to do **exact** computations, you should be using [`integer`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_intege.htm)s (e.g., representing currency as a number of cents, not dollars) or [`ratio`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_ratio.htm)s.

Answer (score 10):

Floating point numbers are not necessarily exact. Typically an implementation has single and double floats. There might be also short and long floats.

Single float

```
CL-USER 7 > (+ -380 -158.27 -35.52)
-573.79004
```

Now with double floats:

```
CL-USER 8 > (+ -380 -158.27d0 -35.52d0)
-573.79D0
```

LispWorks thus has two different float types (possibly short-float is a third, depending of 32bit or 64bit architecture):

```
CL-USER 9 > (describe 35.52)

35.52 is a SINGLE-FLOAT

CL-USER 10 > (describe 35.52d0)

35.52D0 is a DOUBLE-FLOAT
```

See also: [`*read-default-float-format*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_rd_def.htm#STread-default-float-formatST).